# when fast cliking on like button getting unknown likes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am working on project which have like unlike function look like facebook but i am getting stuck when i click multiple time at once on like button or unlike button then its work like firing and if i have 1 or 2 like and i click many time fast fast then my likes gone in -2 -1. how i solve this issue ? if when click many time always get perfect result. below my jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".like").click(function () {
        var ID = $(this).attr("idl");
        var REL = $(this).attr("rel");
        var owner = $(this).attr("owner");
        var URL = 'box_like.php';
        var dataString = 'msg_id=' + ID + '&rel=' + REL + '&owner=' + owner;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: URL,
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                if (REL == 'Like') {
                    $('.blc' + ID).html('Unlike:').attr('rel', 'Unlike').attr('title', 'Unlike');
                    $('.spn' + ID).html(html);
                } else {
                    $('.blc' + ID).attr('rel', 'Like').attr('title', 'Like').html('Like:');
                    $('.spn' + ID).html(html);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Disable the button within the `click` code you posted (very first line), than once it is successful in the ajax code, re-enable the button at the end of the success function.

Comment: @SolomonClosson i am using <a for lke unlike and i try to remove class but it not work i dont know why :' (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the async nature of ajax request.... when you click on the element continuously... the click event will get fired before the response from previous request come back and the link status is updated to next one

Case:
Assume the `rel` is unlike, then before the response came back again another click happens so the `rel` is not yet updated so you are sending another `unlike` request to server instead of a like request

Try below solution(Not Tested)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var xhr;
    $(".like").click(function () {
        var ID = $(this).attr("idl");
        var REL = $(this).attr("rel");
        var owner = $(this).attr("owner");
        var URL = 'box_like.php';
        var dataString = 'msg_id=' + ID + '&rel=' + REL + '&owner=' + owner;
        if (REL == 'Like') {
            $('.blc' + ID).html('Unlike:').attr('rel', 'Unlike').attr('title', 'Unlike');
        } else {
            $('.blc' + ID).attr('rel', 'Like').attr('title', 'Like').html('Like:');
        }

        //abort the previous request since we don't know the response order
        if (xhr) {
            xhr.abort();
        }

        xhr = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: URL,
            data: dataString,
            cache: false
        }).done(function (html) {
            $('.spn' + ID).html(html);
        }).always(function () {
            xhr = undefined;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: can you ad sucess funciton in this ?

Comment: @user2800453 what do you want to do in success?

Comment: hmm look @ my question sucess function(html) i get likes values. return from php file

Comment: @user2800453 yes you can add that

Comment: :- )) its working fine on my lappy.  hope fine in domain. thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 1):

Set a variable, we'll call it `stop` and toggle it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var stop = false;
    $(".like").click(function () {
        if (!stop)
        {
            stop = true;
            var ID = $(this).attr("idl");
            var REL = $(this).attr("rel");
            var owner = $(this).attr("owner");
            var URL = 'box_like.php';
            var dataString = 'msg_id=' + ID + '&rel=' + REL + '&owner=' + owner;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: URL,
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    if (REL == 'Like') {
                        $('.blc' + ID).html('Unlike:').attr('rel', 'Unlike').attr('title', 'Unlike');
                        $('.spn' + ID).html(html);
                    } else {
                        $('.blc' + ID).attr('rel', 'Like').attr('title', 'Like').html('Like:');
                        $('.spn' + ID).html(html);
                    }
                }
            }).always(function() { stop = false; });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: in that case you need to use the `complete` handler to set `stop=false` else if there was an failed request then you will not be able to click again till the page is reloaded

Comment: again `success` and [done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) are the same... you need to use [always](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/)

Comment: @SolomonClosson and arun p johny Bohot Achey Larkon . translate =-> Very good boys :- p thanq to you guyz take care

Comment: They should change the name from `.done` to `.success` than, if you ask me!  Cause, they have a `.fail`, so why don't they have `.success`?